# Ruby expression not evaluating to what I'm expecting

Tags: ruby

```
string = "test"
suitable_inventories = [1, 2, 3]
inventories ||= string.empty? ? suitable_inventories : []   
inventories
```

Based on my understanding of Ruby, I was expecting the above code to produce:

```
[]
```

Instead, it is returning:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Did I misunderstand how `||=` works?

Comment: code works fine for me.  Are you sure inventories isn't set earlier?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. With the code you've written above, `inventories` does indeed equal `[]`. You must have already set that variable earlier in the code. Voting to close.

Comment: Even if it's set earlier, wouldn't this piece of code re-assign it?

Comment: No. Because you're using `||=`, not `=`.

Comment: No `||=` is an operator that keeps you from re-assigning to an assigned variable

Comment: It dependent on the existing 'truthiness' of `inventories` since you are using `||=` That tests `inventories` first. If you want the assignment to be based solely on the ternary, use `=` instead.

Comment: "No ||= is an operator that keeps you from re-assigning to an assigned variable". Not quite. It assigns if the variable is unassigned, is nil, or is false.

Comment: This code is just plain baffling. You should probably restructure this into a method and order it in a more logical way, plus show how it might be used in a way that exercises both blank and non-blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a ||= b` means `a || a = b` that is,

- If a is set (not `nil` or `false`), then `a` remains as it is, using short-circuit behaviour of `||` operator
- Otherwise, `a` will be false or nil resulting in execution of second part of expression after `||`, i.e `a=b`

In your case, `inventories` must be already assigned (not `nil`) thats why it is not []

```
inventories ||= string.empty? ? suitable_inventories : []
```

is equivalent to :

```
inventories || inventories = string.empty? ? suitable_inventories : []
```

Answer (score 4):

`||=` is a conditional assignment. The below two are basically equivalent:

```
foo ||= 42
bar = 42 unless bar
```

In other words `||=` will do an assignment only if the variable holds `nil` or `false` as a value ATM. Due to some peculiarities, this also means variable that didn't have a value assigned already.

---

So if `inventories` already holds some array, a new one will not be reassigned with `||=`.

Comment: They are "basically equivalent", but it's important to note that `foo ||= 42` will return the value of foo, whether it was already truthy, or was just now set to 42. On the other hand, `bar = 42 unless bar` will return 42 if bar was not previously truthy, but will return `nil` if bar was already assigned. This has implications for the common custom attr_reader pattern: `def foo; @foo ||= calculate_foo; end`. In this case, replacing `||=` with `=...unless` would not produce the desired result.